# Can one authenticate the license of Win10 with the one different from the one used during the first-time installation?

Tags: windows, license, windows-authentication

When I booted a Win10 machine that I hadn't used for a long time, I noticed that I forgot to complete the license authentication and the OS was installed with the license used for also the other machine. In other words, I use one license in two machines. On the other hand, there are OS installers with licenses that are not yet used. The Win10 machine that I have not used for a long time tends to say "authenticate with the license" at every startup. Is it okay to enter the license code that I am not using at the installation time? Will he say, "Is it a difference license code from your OS installation time?" It would be of great help if you could suggest a nice work-around. Due to several reasons, I cannot adopt an option reinstalling the OS again.

Comment: “The Win10 machine that I have not used for a long time tends to say "authenticate with the license" at every startup. Is it okay to enter the license code that I am not using at the installation time?” - Are you by chance providing a translation of the message? One doesn’t provide a license authentication, by chance, do you mean **activation**? Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Answer (score 0):

Most Windows licensing is OEM and you cannot use that on a second machine. OEM licensing cannot be moved.

Retail licensing can be moved but it cannot be used on two computers at the same time.

Volume licensing is managed by Keys in the Microsoft Server. This is Company licensing and you do not likely have this.

So if you have the same license on two computers, you will at some point have an issue. If you just moved the license and it is not OEM, you should be fine.

You say you cannot reinstall to correct this, so then you need to purchase an additional Windows 10 license.